# How to get the current startup project's physical location in VB.NET or C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, reflection, filepath

I want the location of the current execution project i.e in VB.NET/C# or the current class file's path?

Ok,let me elaborate i got 2 projects in one solution file,lets say A,B are projects, my startup project is B ,and im accessing a class file in A ,now i need to know virtual path of B. because i need it for accessing the resource file coz error pops up when using ExpressionBuilderContext

Comment: What do you need it for?

Comment: It is worth noting that most paths used if given relative, (eg "config.xml") it is relative to the working directory of the exe

Comment: yes true ,but i want to do it using ExpressionbuilderContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

String strPath = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase);

Comment: Ok,let me elaborate i got 2 projects in one solution file,lets say A,B are projects, my startup project is B ,and im accessing a class file in A ,now i need to know virtual path of B. because i need to for accessing the resource file coz error pops up when using ExpressionBuilderContext

Answer (score 2):

Under VB.net in Visual Studio 2008 I've been using the following :

```
Application.StartupPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these:

```
        Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase);
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.WriteLine(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        Console.WriteLine();
```